# Mapping JSON to Core Data objects

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a WS Witch return to me a JSON structure. I would like to create the Data structure (class,Objects) with the JSON and create the CoreData modele witch represente the JSON Structure. Any Advice ? Help ?

thanks for your answers.

Comment: Generally: JSON object = NSDictionary, JSON array = NSArray, JSON string = NSString, JSON number = NSNumber, JSON true/false = NSNumber, JSON null = NSNull or nil or NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement before and I used [this blog](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/) as my guide. You obviously have to create a data-model with attributes mapped to the incoming JSON structure. The above blog also covers some special cases so it should be through reference, if not a complete one. It will at least give you a good heads-up as to where you can go next!